# What does "how's your face?" mean in Ant-Man?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, ant-man, ant-man-2015

In the first scene of Ant-Man,

> Hank Pym smacks Mitchell Carson's head, causing a nose bleed. Then a few scenes afterwards, it is 25 years later an Hank asks Mitchell "how's your face?" The meaning would be obvious except for the fact that Mitchell Carson looks identical 25 years later. So how does Mitchell look the same?

**What was Hank really asking?**

Comment: Why would him looking the same change the meaning of what is said? What makes you think the obvious answer is not the correct one? He's not *asking* anything, he's saying "hey, remember when I gave you a nosebleed, that was fun".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Hank is taunting him about the time he smashed his face into a desk, while reminding him that he is still a formidable and quick to anger individual and that if Carson would like his face to remain unbloodied he had better not anger Hank.

Its not some deep sci-fi metaphor, Hank just wants to punch him.

Answer (score 1):

"How's your face?" refers to the prologue scene in the beginning of the movie,in which Henry Pym is angry at Howard Stark for attempting to steal his formula(big surprise there...NOT)and the man he was talking to made some insensitve comment, at which point he slammed his face into a desk, although why he didn't attack Howard since he's the one he was mad at, I don't know